# Jqgrid Add/update/delete with form modal

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using free version (latest) of jqgrid with MVC c#.
I have set it up with my data and all works fine. I also do have toolbar at the footer with add, edit, delete which when clicked does show the modal form with all the form elements configured. What I am having issues is:

1. How shall I get the all the form elements of my modal pop up
   For example I have this in my col model:

   ```
   { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 90, sorttype: "text", editrules: { required: true }}
   ```

   When the user clicks on the add/edit row I get the name as one of the field in my pop up. So how do I get this field value which the user updated and pass it to my mvc controller.
2. Second ques is on which method can I grab these values for add/edit/delete? I want to grab these values and use ajax to call my server side method.
3. Lastly how shall I refresh the grid after add/edit/delete.

Updated: I am using below code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        var $grid = $("#list");             
        $grid.jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")',
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'Get',
            colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Address'],
            loadonce: true,
            height: '100%',
            autowidth: true,
   colModel: [
                { name: 'uid', index: 'uid', editable: true,  editrules: { required: true}},
                { name: 'name', index: 'name', editable: true,  editrules: { required: true}},
                { name: 'sex', index: 'sex', editable: true,  editrules: { required: true}},
                { name: 'address', index: 'address', editable: true,  editrules: { required: true}}
     ],
            cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true, editable: true },
            autoResizing: { compact: true, resetWidthOrg: true },                
            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, "10000:All"],
            viewrecords: true,
            autoencode: true,
            sortable: true,              
            pager: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            sortname: "uid",
            sortorder: "desc",
            pagerRightWidth: 150,
            afterAddRow: function () {

            },
            afterSetRow: function () {

            },
            afterDelRow: function () {

            },
            inlineEditing: {
                keys: true
            },
            formEditing: {
                width: 310,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                savekey: [true, 13]
            },
            searching: {                    
                loadFilterDefaults: false,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                searchOperators: true,
                searchOnEnter: true
            },

            caption: "MyData"
        }).jqGrid("navGrid")
        .editGridRow("new", properties);              
    });
   </script>
```

Where above can I use ajax to call my mvc controller as:

```
    $.ajax({
       url: '/Home/AddNew',
       type: 'POST',
       async: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       processData: false,
       data: {
                //I try to use below code to get value but it returned null
                uid: $('input#uid').val()
             },
        success: function (data) { }
       });
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post more full JavaScript code, which you use. Do you use `editurl` option with some URL to your controller action? You can use Developer Tools and examine Network tab to see, which information will be send to `editurl` URL in case of all add/edit/delete operations. Finally you should use correct tags to your question. You can examine [jqgrid-asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid-asp.net/info) to see that it's for **commercial** product. You should replace it [free-jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/free-jqgrid/info) if you use "free jqGrid".

Comment: Hi oleg I have included my code and removed the tag. So again what I want to know is how can I get the form element that are in my modal pop up, which event to get these and pass it to  my ajax mthod and then how to refresh the grid. Thanks

Comment: Do you tried to add `editurl` option to jqGrid? You will be able to see the posted data in Network tab of Developer Tools. The format is documented [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server), [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server1) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server2). It#s very easy to implement the corresponding ASP.NET MVC action, which process the requests on the server.

Comment: I have added  editurl: '/Home/AddNew' and it does work and I get all the params of the form together with the operation. So wanted to check how can I pass an extra param apart from the form params. Also how can I manually refresh the grid.

Comment: There are many ways to do that. The main problem: I try to hold compatibility to old versions of jqGrid (version <=4.7) and old versions contains **different callbacks** for different editing modes (form editing, inline editing and cell editing). You use currently form editing and to post additional parameters you can use for example object returned from `onclickSubmit` callback or from jqGridAddEditClickSubmit jQuery event. For example, you can include `onclickSubmit: function (options, postdata, editOrAdd) { return { myparam: $("#someInput").val() }; }` inside of `formEditing`.

Comment: Sorry oleg could you give me an example of how to use these. I tried by commenting out the edit url and used this code.  var gr = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('delGridRow', gr, {
            reloadAfterSubmit: true,
            onclickSubmit: function (params) {
                alert('clicked delete');
            }
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there are some misunderstanding how editing in jqGrid work. There are exist `editurl` parameter of jqGrid, which default value is `"clientArray"` in free jqGrid. It means that changes of data will be done *locally* without posting any data to the server. If you specify for example `editurl: '/Home/Change'` then jqGrid will POST the data modifications to the server and `Change` action should do adding, editing or deleting the data.

If you want so send *additional data* together with editing data then you should use additional options/callbacks for that. The options/callbacks depends on the editing mode which you use. You use currently form editing. To be exact you use `navGrid` method, which adds navigator bar with Add/Edit/Delete buttons. After the user clicks on the buttons, fills the corresponding forms and press Submit button jqGrid (`navGrid`) executes `editGridRow` or `delGridRow` method. One can control the options used by `navGrid` during the calls of `editGridRow` or `delGridRow` method using options of `navGrid` oder by specifying the options inside of `formEditing` or `formDeleting` options of jqGrid. For example you can modify your code to

```
cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true, editable: true },
editurl: "/Home/Change",
formEditing: {
    width: 310,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    savekey: [true, 13],
    onclickSubmit: function (options, postData, editOrAdd) {
        return {
            myparam: $("#someInput").val()
        };
    }
},
formDeleting: {
    onclickSubmit: function (options, postData, formRowIds) {
        return {
            myDelParam: $("#someInput").val()
        };
    }
}
```

The above code will send *the default editing parameters* to the server *and* additional parameter `myparam` or `myDelParam`. The object returned from `onclickSubmit` will be combined with the object with other editing data of jqGrid. So send more as one additional parameter you need just return object with more as one property.

If you don't want to use common URL `editurl` for all editing operations you can use `url` option defined *inside of* `formEditing` or/and `formDeleting`. You can use `url` defined as function if you want. For exymple,

```
cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true, editable: true },
formEditing: {
    url: function (rowid, editOrAdd, postData, options) {
        // editOrAdd is "add" or "edit"
        return editOrAdd === "add" ? "/Home/Add" : "/Home/Edit";
    },
    width: 310,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    savekey: [true, 13],
    onclickSubmit: function (options, postData, editOrAdd) {
        if (editOrAdd === "add") {
            return {
                myAddParam: $("#someInput").val()
            };
        } else {
            return {
                myEditParam: $("#someInput").val()
            };
        }
    }
},
formDeleting: {
    url: "/Home/Delete",
    onclickSubmit: function (options, postData, formRowIds) {
        return {
            myDelParam: $("#someInput").val()
        };
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**: to reload the modified data **from the server** in case of using `loadonce: true` one can add `reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true }` option inside of `formEditing`, `formDeleting` and `navOptions`. Like

```
cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true, editable: true },
formEditing: {
    url: function (rowid, editOrAdd, postData, options) {
        // editOrAdd is "add" or "edit"
        return editOrAdd === "add" ? "/Home/Add" : "/Home/Edit";
    },
    width: 310,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    savekey: [true, 13],
    reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true },
    onclickSubmit: function (options, postData, editOrAdd) {
        if (editOrAdd === "add") {
            return {
                myAddParam: $("#someInput").val()
            };
        } else {
            return {
                myEditParam: $("#someInput").val()
            };
        }
    }
},
formDeleting: {
    url: "/Home/Delete",
    reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true },
    onclickSubmit: function (options, postData, formRowIds) {
        return {
            myDelParam: $("#someInput").val()
        };
    }
},
navOptions: {
    reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true }
}
```

The option `fromServer: true` will be forwarded to `reloadGrid` event and the data will be loaded from the server instead of local reloading.

Comment: Thanks Oleg I got this working now. The only thing is during add/edit/delete the grid does not auto refeshes with the updates. I have to refresh the page to see the changes. I have even added reloadAfterSubmit:true  to formEditiing but still does not refreshes.  Also when I click the refresh button in the toolbar below it does nothing.

Comment: @aman: You are welcome! It could be multiple reasons of the problem. The first one: you could have some caching problems on the server side. I personally add `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge (new TimeSpan (0));` line in all GET methods. It adds HTTP header `Cache-Control: private, max-age=0`, which send always the data to the server.

Comment: @aman: The second reason could be on the client side if you use `loadonce: true`. Reloading of data (after previous filtering for example) could be made **locally** from previously loaded data. To force reloading from the server one have to reset `datatype` from "local" back to "json". The option `fromServer: true` of `reloadGrid` helps here. `reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true }` option of `formEditing`, `formDeleting` and `navOptions` could help here. See **UPDATED** part of my answer

Comment: reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true } works fine. Now everything works fine. Add/Edit/Delete.  I have question about styling jqgrid, shall I ask it here or should open a new thread.

Comment: @aman: It's better to ask new questions always in separate thread because the questions/answers will be indexed and be used by searching engine. More specific questions can be better indexed and found by other users of stackoverflow.